# In Emacs, how do I select the completion list with the keyboard?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, minibuffer

When I tab-complete in a minibuffer and Emacs displays a completion list in a new buffer, how do I switch to that buffer without using the mouse?

I tried `C-x o`, but that just switched to the first buffer, out of which I entered the minibuffer.

I also tried `C-x b`, but that gives me `command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer`.

Lastly I tried `C-x <C-right>`, which gives me `cannot switch buffers in minibuffer window`.

EDIT: I spoke about minibuffer completion in my example, but being able to access the completion list (using the keyboard) from within a regular buffer is also important to me, and not working. The `M-v` shortcut was suggested, but it only seems to work inside the minibuffer accessed by `M-x`, in every other buffer I've tried, `M-v` is bound to `scroll down command` and does not switch to the completion list. I doesn't even seem to work in other minibuffers. For example, it doesn't work in the shell command minibuffer invoked by `M-!` either.

Comment: See my suggestion in the edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

You can use <kbd>M-v</kbd> (documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Commands.html)) which switches to the completion buffer and puts the cursor on the first completion:

> Typing M-v, while in the minibuffer, selects the window showing the
>   completion list (switch-to-completions). This paves the way for using
>   the commands below. `<PageUp>` or `<prior>` does the same. You can also
>   select the window in other ways...

EDIT: It looks like based on your edit to the original question that what you're asking for is a way to switch to the completions buffer more globally. There is a function `switch-to-completions` that selects the completions list - you might consider binding that function to a key of your choosing, e.g.:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x t") 'switch-to-completions)
```

For example, such a binding allows me to switch to completions from "Shell command: " invoked by <kbd>M-!</kbd>, and places the cursor on the first possible completion.

Comment: Weirly enough, this does not seem to work for me. (I'm using Emacs v24.2.1 btw.) When I press `M-v` in the minibuffer it just says `Beginning of buffer` and doesn't select the completion list.

Comment: Odd. What about pressing `PageUp` - that should work as well (on my Mac that's `fn-Up`). You might try restarting Emacs without reading your initialization file, ie `emacs -q`

Comment: You may have `M-v` bound to some other function.

Comment: It works when I enter the minibuffer with `M-x`, however it does not work when I try to access the completion list from other minibuffers like `M-!` or from any "normal" buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> twice, or use <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, which switches to the previous buffer instead of the next one.

Comment: `C-x o` twice does not work, because the first command closes the completion list. Applying a negative argument to the buffer switch command however does work well. I'd use `C-- C-x o` though. Also, it does not insert the cursor at the first completion, but the beginning of the buffer, which sucks because I then have to move all the way down. Is this really how people use completion?

Comment: bug: No, I suspect that very few people actually interact directly with the completion buffer. The normal approach is simply to continue filtering the options by typing and `TAB`ing in the minibuffer until a unique result is obtained, with the completion buffer acting only as a visual reference.