# Code Completion in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am trying to use Emacs, because it seems a little bit nicer than Notepad++.

I am trying to use the code completion feature (a.k.a intellisense), but don't know how to do it.

First, I type in `M-x`, then `eval-expression`, then in the minibuffer, I want to type in

`(print (font-family-list))`

So I type in `(print (font-f` and then press `TAB`, I get a window with the content:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
font-face-attributes
font-family-list
```

I can use my mouse to click on the second option (`font-family-list`). But how do I select the option using only my keyboard?  What are the shortcut keys?

Comment: Just enter the character that differentiates the possibilities, i.e. `m` in this case.

Comment: You can use `M-:` instead of `M-x eval-expression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really asking the same question as:

> [In Emacs, how do I select the completion list with the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084039/in-emacs-how-do-i-select-the-completion-list-with-the-keyboard)

From the [Completion Commands doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Commands.html) and the above answer, I realised that I need to be executing `switch-to-completions` function.  Because `M-v` wasn't working for me, I ended up binding Shift-Tab to switch to the completions window while in the minibuffer:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map  (kbd "<S-tab>") 'switch-to-completions)
```

**EDIT:** M-v (or Alt-v) is working for me on a fresh install - however since using `cua-mode`, it stopped working.

I was about to install [minibuffer-complete-cycle](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/minibuffer-complete-cycle.el) but then when I was reading the description, it says that if `completion-cycle-threshold` variable is set to a an integer, say `3`, then if there are `3` or fewer completion options, then `TAB` will cycle through them.  We can still use `M-v` with it.

Though reading its description, `minibuffer-complete-cycle` seems a bit more polished.

Answer (score 2):

In these situations, completion is done via <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Completion will add any unique characters until there is a collision (in your case, it added the letter "a"). At this point you need to type the next character that differentiates it. If you type <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> Emacs will select `font-family-list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a better completion system, but not in the mini-buffer that you call with `eval-expression` or `M-:`.

I suggest you call the interactive inferior elisp shell with `M-x ielm`. Now you can enable the completion of `company-mode` which brings something like this:

[image: company-mode completion in shell-mode]

Install company, which is in [melpa](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/MELPA):

```
package-install RET company RET
```

and call it when you want:

```
M-x company-mode
```

You'll notice it works in a shell and in other languages :)

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion. But a minibuffer drop down list would be good for org-mode.  Still searching for a solution.  Will change my answer if I find something.