# can I select it without more alphabet in emacs?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

[image]

I am in above picture. I want to select common-media-session.h, but I always select it using tab or c-n or c-p in vim.

Can I go to next candidate like vim?

Comment: It’s not the canonical way, but `C-M-/` (perhaps more than once) would work here.

Comment: This question seems about emacs and the evil-mode. Remove the tag "vim" and add "evil-mode".

Comment: I recommend you to use narrowing framework. Helm or Ivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `icomplete-mode`, then you can use `C-.` and `c-,` to move to the next/previous candidate.

If you set `completion-cycling` to a non-nil value, then you can simply hit TAB several times until you get to the completion you want.

Personally, I'd just type `com-s.h TAB` instead.

Answer (score 1):

*M-v* to switch to the completion list and *C-n* to select. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084039/in-emacs-how-do-i-select-the-completion-list-with-the-keyboard).

Comment: I am using evil. Thus I can't switch to completion window.

Comment: I'm not familiar with evil, Maybe you set your own hot key to *switch-to-completions*?

Comment: No, I can't switch to completion in minibuffer.